# Read int value in thread safe way

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, lock-free, interlocked

I have
`int counter`
And have increment it in multithread by
`Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);`
Is thread safe reading it in other thread (while others still incrementing it) like this:
`int localSaved = counter;`
or
`int localSaved = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref counter, 0, 0);`?
Not really know how 'Interlocked.CompareExchange' work but found it in google.

Comment: Some good answers on the "duplicate," but when you read them, pay attention to the question that some of the "answers" ask back: What does "thread-safe" even mean in this context? Suppose your "reader" thread copies the "correct" value of `counter` into `localSaved`. What then? By the time your reader thread does anything with `localSaved`, the `counter` could already have changed, maybe more than once. If that's not a problem for you, then your idea (if not your actual code) is "thread-safe." But it might be a problem for somebody else, and for them the same exact idea is not "thread-safe."